# text on horizontal form doesnt align vertically

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a extremely simple Bootstrap 3 horizontal form with a row with 3 columns
Column 1 is a label referencing column2
Column 2 is a input textbox
Column 3 is a descripting text

Column 1 is aligned vertically with column2 textbox but column3 appears to be upper than the other.
[image: What i get]

¿What i´m doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<form class="form-horizontal" name="frmBuscar" id="frmBuscar" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-lg-6" for="txt1">Campo 1:</label>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<input name="txt1" id="txt1" value="100" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 ">
Unidad 1
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
       Unidad 1 
</div>
```

TO

```
<div class="control-label  col-lg-1">
       Unidad 1
</div>
```

Comment: That works for me.
Now, I have to align texto to left but I suposse that can use text-left to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using columns is necessarily the best way to go with this; you could use `display: flex` on the `.form-group` container and just align everything to the end of the container; also you need to remove the margin for the `label` and there you go.

Also for some reason I was not able to get the look on your picture with just the HTML you provided, but I works almost the same way with the CSS I worte, second form is your markup

```css
.form-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form class="" name="frm" id="frm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="" for="txt1">
              Campo 1:
         </label>
    <div class="">
      <input name="txt1" id="txt1" value="100" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="">
      Unidad 1
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


<form class="form-horizontal" name="frm" id="frm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-6" for="txt1">
              Campo 1:
         </label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <input name="txt1" id="txt1" value="100" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      Unidad 1
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It´s true that with your snippet the issue is not showing
I edited to with full code.
Gopi answer worked for me